# Group items in a ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I have a super simple ActivityList, say a scoll list with all countries. Now, I would like to group the countries by continent like:

- Azia

  - China
  - India
- Europe

  - France
  - Greece

The Android Contacts application has a similar behavior (the A, B, C,.. groups for your contacts). I played with [cwac-merge](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) but it doesn't have the same behavior (groups don't stick at the top when you scroll for example).

Is there a simple way to do this on Android?

Thanks for helping out a fellow programmer who tries to learn how Android works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need 2-level lists, then use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). You can find examples for it in the ApiDemos I believe.

Comment: Thanks, indeed for this example an ExpandableListView will do. Hadn't looked at it that way.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at this project [AmazingListView](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/). The source code for it and also source for a demo is available.

Comment: For now I'm pleased with the ExpandableListView but the list view you link too looks, well, amazing. Definitely will bookmark this for a more complex use case! Thanks.

Comment: @Cimm: Glad you've found something that works for you. Good luck.